# Requesting Oauth Google authrization from Service

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, dotnetopenauth

I am in Web Service Environment and I am interacting with Google API for OAuth. I have seen some samples from ASPX model where they call

```
GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization(googleClient,ANY GOOGLE APP Scope);
```

it works fine. BUT when I am in service environment. it returns "Unauthorized token". Basically, in web environment, user would be redirected to a webpage where he/she would enter his/her credentials and GogoleAPI would return accesstoken for that.

I am not sure how is this supposed to work when RequestAuthorization() is residing on the service side. Can somebody please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RequestAuthorization` call must be made while the user is authorizing the service.  After that, the token the site obtains may be stored so that the service environment may use that token later.